# How to create n datasets of size N with same mean but different standard deviation?

Tags: means

I am looking to create 400 datasets of size 180 numbers with the same mean but a different standard deviation. Is there a way to do this other than trial and error? Possibly some way to automate this process?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What have you tried?

Notice that if $M$ is the targt mean, then for each $x\in \mathbb{R}$ a pair of data points $(M+x, M-x)$ have mean $M$ and contribute $2x^2$ to the variance. Can you think of how to use this observation to craft however many datasets with mean $M$ and distinct standard deviations you wish?

Answer (score 0):

If you know Java, you can use [Random.nextGaussian()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextGaussian()) to get a dataset with mean 0 and standard deviation $\sqrt{N}$.  Multiplying each number in the dataset by the ratio of this to the desired standard deviation will get you to the standard deviation you want, and *then* (note the order) adding the desired mean to each will then get you the mean you want.